# Find symmetric words in a text

Tags: python, function

I have to write a function which takes one arguments text containing a block of text in the form of a str, and returns a sorted list of “symmetric” words. A symmetric word is defined as a word where for all values i, the letter i positions from the start of the word and the letter i positions from the end of the word are equi-distant from the respective ends of the alphabet. For example, bevy is a symmetric word as: b (1 position from the start of the word) is the second letter of the alphabet and y (1 position from the end of the word) is the second-last letter of the alphabet; and e (2 positions from the start of the word) is the fifth letter of the alphabet and v (2 positions from the end of the word) is the fifth-last letter of the alphabet.

For example:

```
>>> symmetrics("boy bread aloz bray")
['aloz','boy']
>>> symmetrics("There is a car and a book;")
['a']
```

All I can think about the solution is this but I can't run it since it's wrong:

```
def symmetrics(text):
    func_char= ",.?!:'\/"
    for letter in text:
        if letter in func_char:
          text = text.replace(letter, ' ') 
    alpha1 = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    alpha2 = 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'
    sym = []
    for word in text.lower().split():
        n = range(0,len(word))
        if word[n] == word[len(word)-1-n]:
            sym.append(word)
        return sym
```

The code above doesn't take into account the position of alpha1 and alpha2 as I don't know how to put it. Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: What do you want to do with **text = text.replace(letter, ' ')**? According to your description, with a space, a word could never be symmetric, unless the space is in middle.

Comment: `alpha1` can be replaced by the `string` module constant `string.ascii_lowercase`, and its reverse can be `string.ascii_lowercase[::-1]` (slice with negative step).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hint:

```
In [16]: alpha1.index('b')
Out[16]: 1

In [17]: alpha2.index('y')
Out[17]: 1
```

An alternative way to approach the problem is by using the [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method:

```
import string

def is_sym(word):
    alpha1 = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    alpha2 = 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'
    tr = string.maketrans(alpha1, alpha2)
    n = len(word) // 2
    return word[:n] == word[::-1][:n].translate(tr)

print(is_sym('aloz'))
print(is_sym('boy'))
print(is_sym('bread'))
```

(The building of the translation table can be easily factored out.)

Comment: I really like the simple elegance of comparing the word and a reversed, translated version of it.  But doesn't this fail for words with an odd number of characters?  For example, doesn't this fail for `boy`?

You can still do it this way if you use the length to figure out how many characters N can be compared, then take a slice of length N from the start, and see if the slice of length N from the end matches when reversed and translated.

Comment: @steveha: Oh yes it does. I completely missed that. Thanks for pointing out. Will fix the code in a moment.

Comment: Can a string with odd number of characters (written in an alphabet with an even number of characters) be symmetric in the first place?

Comment: @heltonbiker: Not in my initial understanding of the problem. However, in the OP's examples both `boy` and `a` are considered symmetric, which leads me to conclude that the middle letter is not part of the symmetry criterion.

Comment: @NPE, I think we have to go by the examples provided, which clearly showed that `'boy'` was to be considered symmetric.

Comment: @steveha: Sure, that's what the current code in the answer does.

Comment: @NPE, of course I saw that!  I was just agreeing with your answer to heltonbiker's question.  :-)  I have already voted your answer up now that it matches the spec of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop could be modified as:

```
for word in text.lower().split():
    for n in range(0,len(word)//2):
        if alpha1.index(word[n]) != alpha2.index(word[len(word)-1-n]):
            break
    else:
        sym.append(word)
return sym
```

Comment: Correct me but it will throw an exception

Comment: @ArtsiomRudzenka It should work now. The original range() is incorrect also.

Comment: @Sheng it only works for the first example but not for the second one :/

Comment: @Sheng and I'm sorry, what does '//2' means?

Comment: @FynnMahoney What is the error? It works on my Python3 in both cases. //2 means evenly divided by 2

Comment: @Sheng I'm using python 2.x.x It says  File "<pyshell#0>", line 11, in symmetrics
    if alpha1.index(word[n]) != alpha2.index(word[len(word)-1-n]):
ValueError: substring not found

Comment: @FynnMahoney Oh....You forget to replace ";" with "space"

Comment: @Sheng oh yeah thanks! and one more thing, for the second example, it returns ['a','a'] instead of ['a']. how do i fix that?

Comment: @FynnMahoney Try list(set(sym)).

Answer (score 0):

According to your symmetric rule, we may verify a symmetric word with the following `is_symmetric_word` function:

```
def is_symmetric_word(word):
    alpha1 = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    alpha2 = 'zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'
    length = len(word)
    for i in range(length / 2):
        if alpha1.index(word[i]) != alpha2.index(word[length - 1 - i]):
            return False

    return True
```

And then the whole function to get all unique symmetric words out of a text can be defined as:

```
def is_symmetrics(text):
    func_char= ",.?!:'\/;"
    for letter in text:
        if letter in func_char:
          text = text.replace(letter, ' ') 
    sym = []
    for word in text.lower().split():
        if is_symmetric_word(word) and not (word in sym):
            sym.append(word)

    return sym
```

The following are two test cases from you:

```
is_symmetrics("boy bread aloz bray")           #['boy', 'aloz']
is_symmetrics("There is a car and a book;")    #['a']
```

Comment: it seems that i can't run it in my python console :/

Comment: @FynnMahoney If you just copy the code into Python console, you may need to pay attention to the blank lines among the code. A suggestion is to copy the code into an editor (like notepad in Windows or vim in Linux), remove the blank links, and then copy to Python console. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Code first.  Discussion below the code.

```
import string

# get alphabet and reversed alphabet
try:
    # Python 2.x
    alpha1 = string.lowercase
except AttributeError:
    # Python 3.x and newer
    alpha1 = string.ascii_lowercase

alpha2 = alpha1[::-1]  # use slicing to reverse alpha1

# make a dictionary where the key, value pairs are symmetric
# for example symd['a'] == 'z', symd['b'] == 'y', and so on
_symd = dict(zip(alpha1, alpha2))

def is_symmetric_word(word):
    if not word:
        return False  # zero-length word is not symmetric
    i1 = 0
    i2 = len(word) - 1
    while True:
        if i1 >= i2:
            return True  # we have checked the whole string
        # get a pair of chars
        c1 = word[i1]
        c2 = word[i2]
        if _symd[c1] != c2:
            return False # the pair wasn't symmetric
        i1 += 1
        i2 -= 1

# note, added a space to list of chars to filter to a space
_filter_to_space = ",.?!:'\/ "
def _filter_ch(ch):
    if ch in _filter_to_space:
        return ' '  # return a space 
    elif ch in alpha1:
        return ch # it's an alphabet letter so return it
    else:
        # It's something we don't want.  Return empty string.
        return ''

def clean(text):
    return ''.join(_filter_ch(ch) for ch in text.lower())

def symmetrics(text):
    # filter text: keep only chars in the alphabet or spaces
    for word in clean(text).split():
        if is_symmetric_word(word):
            # use of yield makes this a generator.
            yield word

lst = list(symmetrics("The boy...is a yob."))
print(lst)  # prints: ['boy', 'a', 'yob']
```

- No need to type the alphabet twice; we can reverse the first one.
- We can make a dictionary that pairs each letter with its symmetric letter.  This will make it very easy to test whether any given pair of letters is a symmetric pair.  The function `zip()` makes pairs from two sequences; they need to be the same length, but since we are using a string and a reversed copy of the string, they will be the same length.
- It's best to write a simple function that does one thing, so we write a function that does nothing but check if a string is symmetric.  If you give it a zero-length string it returns `False`, otherwise it sets `i1` to the first character in the string and `i2` to the last.  It compares characters as long as they continue to be symmetric, and increments `i1` while decrementing `i2`.  If the two meet or pass each other, we know we have seen the whole string and it must be symmetric, in which case we return `True`; if it ever finds any pair of characters that are not symmetric, it returns `False`.  We have to do the check for whether `i1` and `i2` have met or passed at the top of the loop, so it won't try to check if a character is its own symmetric character.  (A character can't be both `'a'` and `'z'` at the same time, so a character is never its own symmetric character!)
- Now we write a wrapper that filters out the junk, splits the string into words, and tests each word.  Not only does it convert the chosen punctuation characters to spaces, but it also strips out any unexpected characters (anything not an approved punctuation char, a space, or a letter).  That way we know nothing unexpected will get through to the inner function.  The wrapper is "lazy"... it is a generator that yields up one word at a time, instead of building the whole list and returning that.  It's easy to use `list()` to force the generator's results into a list.  If you want, you can easily modify this function to just build a list and return it.

If you have any questions about this, just ask.

EDIT: The original version of the code didn't do the right thing with the punctuation characters; this version does.  Also, as @heltonbiker suggested, why type the alphabet when Python has a copy of it you can use?  So I made that change too.

EDIT: @heltonbiker's change introduced a dependency on Python version!  I left it in with a suitable `try:`/`except` block to handle the problem.  It appears that Python 3.x has improved the name of the lowercase ASCII alphabet to `string.ascii_lowercase` instead of plain `string.lowercase`.

Comment: No need to type the alphabet, can use `string.ascii_lowercase`, from `string` module ;o)

Comment: @steveha thanks for your generous explanation. i copied everything to my console but when i try to run symmetrics("text"), it says 'symmetric' is not defined?

Comment: Hmm... I just copied everything to my clipboard and pasted it in to Python and it ran correctly.  Did you try it in Python 3.x?  The second version of the code didn't work in Python 3.x, but I just fixed it so it works in both Python 2.x and Python 3.x (and I tested it in both, copying from my web browser and just pasting right in to Python).

Comment: @heltonbiker, thanks for the tip.  But it made my program break in Python 3.x, so I added a `try:` block!